# Trying to hide a process

Tags: c, process

Hello i am trying to hide a process (C/C++) i am using EPROCESS struct and wdm.h header
this is the code:

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <wdm.h>

void main()
{
    PEPROCESS toHide = PsGetCurrentProcess();
    PLIST_ENTRY listtoHide;

    listtoHide = (PLIST_ENTRY)((PUCHAR)toHide + 0x088);
    *((PDWORD)listtoHide->Blink) = (DWORD)listtoHide->Flink;
    *((PDWORD)(listtoHide->Flink) + 1) = (DWORD)listtoHide->Blink;
    listtoHide->Blink = (PLIST_ENTRY)&listtoHide->Flink;
    listtoHide->Flink = (PLIST_ENTRY)&listtoHide->Flink;
}
```

simple and shory but i get error:
"No target architecture"

and a lot of errors that say that some structs and unions are redefinition.
and a lot of other weird errors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[EPROCESS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff544273%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) is a Windows kernel data structure. You can't access it from user code (ring3). This kind of operations are typical of antivirus software or rootkits in addition to kernel drivers.

Short answer: you can't do it with a normal hello world C++ program. You need to study the Windows Driver Model and start programming your way into the kernel world. Start from here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff554690(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: @almog (Unless this isn't your decision to make) I think you should start by rethinking if doing this is really necessary/right thing to do ;)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to make your process invisible you can inject it into Explorer process. The scenario is something like that:

1. call OpenProcess  to open Explorer process
2. call VirtualAllocEx to allocate memory for your code
3. call WriteProcessMemory  to copy your code into the allocated memory
4. call CreateRemoteThread to run your code

As this code can be easily adapted for malicious purposes I am not going into more details.
David Kernin is right, you need to learn a low level programming for solving problems like this one.